can I show model menus one after another?
I need to make applications, but the modal menu only allows me to do 5 questions, how can I show a modal menu after applying another modal menu?
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    const modal1 = new ModalBuilder()
    .setCustomId(`modal1`)
    .setTitle('modal1')
    const ask1 = new TextInputBuilder()
    .setCustomId('ask1')
    .setLabel('1')
    .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
    .setPlaceholder('1')
    .setRequired(true)
    let ask1row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(ask1)
    modal1.addComponents(ask1row)
    const modal2 = new ModalBuilder()
    .setCustomId('modal2')
    .setTitle('modal2')
    const ask2 = new TextInputBuilder()
    .setCustomId('ask2')
    .setLabel("2")
    .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
    .setPlaceholder('2')
    .setRequired(true) 
    let ask2row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(ask2)
    modal2.addComponents(ask2row)
    let buttontest2 = new ButtonBuilder()
    .setCustomId("buttontest2")
    .setLabel("button test 2")
    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
    let buttontest2row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(buttontest2)
if (interaction.customId == "buttontest") {interaction.showModal(modal1)}
if (interaction.customId == "modal1") {interaction.reply({content:"test1", components:[buttontest2row], ephemeral: true})}
if (interaction.customId == "buttontest2") {interaction.showModal(modal2)}
if (interaction.customId == "modal2") {interaction.reply({content:"test2", ephemeral:true})
} 
})

I try something like this.

You cannot respond with a modal to modal interactions.
